# Auto fill google slide template from google spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

Am new to google app script.

Am trying to Auto fill a google slide template with some data from spread sheet.

I created a list in the spreadsheet containing the data.

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('COS Auto Fill').addItem('COS Auto Fill',
    'Presentation_Call').addToUi();
}

function Presentation_Call() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('G1'); 
  var value = range.getValue();
}

function fillTemplate() {
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(Presentation_Call);
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getValues();
  values.forEach(function (row) {
    var templateVariable = row[1];
    var templateValue = row[2];
    presentation.replaceAllText(templateVariable, templateValue);
  });
}
```

Spreadsheet Link

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J11tI2O5NUEr_2HpYYgCrseh9U_0KWF5YJeZ2uOV2gE/edit#gid=0
```

Google Slides Link

```
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/10vGaLWo1ro1d3jzUrEVwOjozHHkxWCMzHEcikqwl_08/edit#slide=id.p1`
```

What I want to do is replacing the {{Number}} in the google slides template with the corresponding data from Gsheet.

By opening the presentation using the presentation ID that is being called from a fixed cell in Gsheet then update the template variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your project:

1. The ID in G1 is enclosed in double quotes. Enter just the plain ID.
2. In `SlidesApp.openById(Presentation_Call)`, you pass in the function, rather than the return value of the function. Change it to `SlidesApp.openById(Presentation_Call())`
3. The function `Presentation_Call` doesn't return anything. Add a `return value;` at the end.
4. You add the function `Presentation_Call` to the menu. But I think you want to call `fillTemplate` instead. So, change that line to `.addItem('COS Auto Fill', 'fillTemplate')`

I made the changes here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GzBgot6Q818rV488Bfx_Q8yknUCvjHUzyInfWob9XzU